# This tag needs [evaluation]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Sorry to disappoint, but this is not a burnination request. But admit that the title made you click... ;)

It is close to it anyway... A synonym/merge request. There is a tag [expression-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expression-evaluation) with a usage guidance:

> Anything related to expression evaluation, i.e. the process of determining the value of an expression in running code.

And there is also [evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation) with the usage:

> Anything related to evaluation of expressions, i.e. the process used to determine the value of expressions in a running program.

Pretty much plagiarized tags...

I doubt there is need to further justify this merge, but just for the record, here are the numbers:

| tag | questions | watchers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation) | 1,237 | 23 |
| [expression-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expression-evaluation) | 172 | 0 |

I am actually not sure about the direction. On the one hand, it is obvious from the numbers that [evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation) should be the *main* tag. On the other hand, I was thinking that maybe a more focus-named tag is better to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: As always in these cases, the evidence is never found in the tag wikis, but always in the *actual usage* of the tags (as in, how are they applied to questions "in the wild")? Are they currently being used identically? If so, then, yes, I agree, this is an obvious case for a merge.

Comment: @CodyGray Good point. After a quick look, it seems that [tag:expression-evaluation] mostly fits to its usage. On the other hand, [tag:evaluation] is also used in the context of ML. It's not my field, but I see contexts of *"evaluate a model"*. See the tag used with [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation+machine-learning) or with [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation+deep-learning). Maybe there could be a separate tag for the ML context?...

Comment: I think this might be closer to a disambiguation request. I'm seeing mathematical operator evaluation, machine learning, comparison (or really a generic concept of evaluating values), something called Expression.Evaluate in Power Query, and a number of questions asking about eval functions (primitive search, [roughly a fourth of the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eval+%5Bevaluation%5D&searchOn=3)), just to name stuff I found on the first three (pagesize 15) pages. Can't really support a direct synonym without some substantial cleanup first

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I agree. Thanks for the initial overview. I will continue a more thorough check of the questions and edit this meta question as a disambiguation request later

Comment: Clickbait has arrived at MSO. Next is [random capitalisation in titles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln1qbgZz_TQ&t=15m48s). Here is [a particularly  bad example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUi6i34yjtg) (a good example of something bad).